# use of the word "assume" in this sentence

Tags: vocabulary

Apologies for the bad question title, I lack sufficient vocabulary. From the vocabulary I know I could not find a duplicate question.

I am having trouble understanding how the word "assume" can be used in this sentence (from [Google define: "Social Proof"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20%22social%20proof%22)):

"**Social proof:**
Social proof, also known as informational social influence, is a psychological phenomenon where people **assume** the actions of others in an attempt to reflect correct behavior for a given situation."

Comment: It means "change in order to imitate", as in "assume the position". It's not always a mental action verb; indeed, like virtually all mental words, it's metaphoric in nature: _Assume x = y_ means 'Change your presuppositions in order to accomodate a hypothetical presupposition that x = y".

Comment: you should make that an answer :)

Comment: The query sentence would have been much easier to make sense of if the Wikipedia author who wrote that definition which Google has spewed forth had written 'imitate' instead of the ambiguous 'assume'. (For that matter, 'reflect' is also ambiguous enough to make it hard to interpret.) It is an example of the worst kind of academic prose: it is verbose, vague and rather pompous.

Comment: @ErikKowal I don't consider using a word like 'assume', in a perfectly usual context, to be  'verbose', 'vague' or 'pompous'. And I am usually the first to complain about excessively elaborate English. I appreciate that the OP may not be a native speaker and with due respect to them, if we are going to 'dumb-down' the language to exclude words like 'assume' in its primary meaning (recognising only its secondary one) then we shall end up with a language fit only for 'dumbos'.

Comment: @WS2 - You have apparently misread both my comment and my intention. I was not complaining about the use of 'assume' when I used the words *verbose, vague* and *pompous*, but the opaqueness of the complete definition of 'social proof' quoted by the OP. Of course I would not wish to exclude words like 'assume' from common use — that would be just silly. My underlying point is that when you are defining a term, you have to take care to do it in a way that leaves the least possible scope for misinterpretation.

Comment: @ErikKowal But even the whole sentence seems straightforward enough: '*Social proof* is a psychological phenomenon where people assume the actions of others in an attempt to reflect correct behaviour...' What's pompous, vague, or verbose about that? Seems perfectly lucid English to me.

Comment: @WS2 - The vagueness lies in the multiplicity of meanings of the term 'assume' (and to a lesser degree, 'reflect'). Even the term 'psychological phenomenon' seems inaccurate to me: surely it is a *behavioural phenomenon,* because it is manifested outwardly. A *psychological phenomenon* is one that takes place in the first instance in someone's mind. The verbosity is evident when you compare the version of the sentence originally quoted with the straightforward manner in which Lambie was able to rewrite it without any loss of meaning.

Comment: I would probably have described it as a *social habit/custom*, but for the fact that *social* had already been used. I would agree that 'psychological phenomenon' is overdoing it. But I see nothing whatever wrong with *assume* but then maybe I simply reflect the English spoken in Britain.

Comment: @ErikKowal I have been in the car all day, and thinking about this again it is clear that *imitate* does not mean exactly the same thing as *assume*. Whilst the former suggests a very deliberate and conscious attempt at portrayal of something, *assume* could mean a quite unconscious action. In the OP's quotation, for all its other shortcomings, I think *assume* is the better word to use.

Comment: @WS2 - I think we're going to have to agree to disagree on this one. However, I did enjoy our discussion. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original meaning of *assume* is "take on": it is still used in this meaning with objects like "role", "position", "authority", but it is rather literary.

So "assume the actions of others" (in a scholarly text) means "take on the actions of those others", or in simpler language, "copy them".

In normal use, the later meaning *draw a conclusion* or more particularly *act on a conclusion drawn* is much more common.

Comment: Yes, it need have nothing whatever to do with imitation. One could say simply 'Assume an upright posture', or 'assume a detached air'. It's other meaning almost parallel's *presume*, and I am just wondering about their etymological relationship.

Comment: The root is _sumo_ = "I take". _as-sumo_ "I take to". _prae-sumo_ = "I take before".

Comment: Just noticed the two typos in my previous comment, both unnecessary apostrophes. I'm using a new computer perhaps it is 'correcting' me.

Answer (score 1):

For me, to assume the actions of others means to: make the actions of others one's own by copying or imitating those actions (behavior). I would have written the sentence differently:
behave as others do in an attempt to act in a manner perceived as correct in a given situation.